# Jenins shell script to build selected branches

Tags: git, jenkins, devops

Sorry if this question is stupid but I don't have much experience in DevOps tasks and do it first time. 
I've GitLab server and Jenkins (installed in Docker container), I've several .NET projects I have a jobs for in Jenkins. I build the projects and do other tasks (deploy builds, send build logs, etc) in bash script.
I want to build only specific branches in every repository.
I can set them manually, but it consumes time and is not easily maintainable (if there is a request to build another branch I need to manually add it to script).
I was thinking about it and made up a possible solution. I have an array consisting names of branches to build, than I loop through the array, checkout to those branch and build every branch. That's how it's working right now. The branch names are entered in the script for each project. I want to store this branch names in a file in root directory of every repository and read this file at the beginning of my script. 
 Is it reasonable approach? Is there other, better solution?

Comment: Instead of having it in a file, why not have it as a global variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've overcome the problem using variables management.
I used [EnvInject](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/) plugin and I'm able to both define this variables in pipeline and in file in repo and provide this file path in pipeline configuration.